# Django dont save my form after signup

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I make a simple website with userena for user registration and a custom form to fill after the signup.

But when the account is created and the form submit datas are'nt stored. After ~1min if i refresh the form and resubmit everything work, but not after a fresh signup/signin

There is my code

models.py

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    game = models.OneToOneField(
                Game,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                verbose_name="related game",
            )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    official = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tournaments = models.ManyToManyField(Tournament, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='created_by')
    team_member = models.ManyToManyField(TeamMember, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class TeamRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team_member_1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 1")
    team_member_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 2")
    team_member_3 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 3")

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [
            'name',
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(TeamRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        team = Team(name=data['name'])
        team.user = self.user
        team.save(commit=False)
        team.team_member.get_or_create(name=data['team_member_1'])
        team.team_member.get_or_create(name=data['team_member_2'])
        team.team_member.get_or_create(name=data['team_member_3'])
        team.save()
```

If someone have an idea? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use one form for team and formsets for team members

[Django formsets documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/)

if you're not going to use formsets then this is another way to it:

**forms.py:**

```
class TeamRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team_member_1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 1")
    team_member_2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 2")
    team_member_3 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Team member 3")

class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields = [
        'name',
        ]
```

**views:**

```
form = TeamRegistrationForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    team = form.save(commit=False)
    team.user = request.user
    team.save()
    member1 = form.cleaned_data.get('team_member_1')
    if member1:
        member1 = TeamMember.objects.get_or_create(name=member1)
        team.team_member.add(member1)
    member2 = form.cleaned_data.get('team_member_2')
    if member2:
        member2 = TeamMember.objects.get_or_create(name=member2)
        team.team_member.add(member2)
    member3 = form.cleaned_data.get('team_member_3')
    if member3:
        member3 = TeamMember.objects.get_or_create(name=member3)
        team.team_member.add(member3)
```

It's not a good way to do this but it's a way you can use.

Comment: I just try your solution i got an error "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'TeamMember'" thanks for your help

Comment: @Bast team gets saved? problem is for members? try printing the variables step by step and check what are they and where is the problem. also you should be able to see the line which caused the error in your error page. if you couldn't find the problem, give me the details of printings and error line so i can check. good luck.